Scale and Shift Signal with Single Op Amp
I am attempting to build a sensor interface for a hall effect sensor to replicate the output of a potentiometer, this is so I can replace the pedal potentiometers in a Logitech G29 with hall effect sensors so a miniature pedal assembly can fit on the wheel itself.
Using the 3.3v supply from the wheel, I want to scale the hall effect sensor output (0.8v, 2.6v) to the measured voltage of the pedals (0.15v to 2.95v). I used the schematic from this post: https://modwiggler.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=253062, with 10kOhm Rg, which calculates Rb=6.751kOhm, and Rf=2.239kOhm.
Simulating this in Simulink I get the expected behaviour:
I selected the Microchip MCP602 for its rail-to-rail output, and because I have two channels in the final version; for now I have set up the unused channel as shown in the datasheet (https://datasheet.ciiva.com/pdfs/VipMasterIC/IC/MCHP/MCHPS02491/MCHPS02491-1.pdf?src-supplier=IHS+Markit).
I have assembled a breadboard test circuit using 3296 trimmer potentiometers for Rb and Rf;  they were calibrated with a DMM before being placed into the circuit.
I am not getting the expected output - the voltage at the output swings between 0.6v and 2v.
After several minutes, nothing is hot, but the resting output voltage with no magnet in front of the hall effect sensor fluctuates slightly.
This is my first project involving analog electronics so I don't really know what I'm doing and why this is happening.

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

While your resistor values are correct, unfortunately you have not considered the acceptable input voltage range of the MCP602. According to the datasheet, page 2, the parameter "Common Mode Input Range" specifies that the inputs should not exceed \$V_{DD}-1.2V\$, which for a 3.3V supply is a maximum of +2.1V. Your expected input will reach +2.6V.
Also you should account for reduced output voltage swing when the output is loaded. Even though many op-amps claim rail-to-rail performance, that's always a lie, and depends heavily on output current. Figure 2-20 from the MCP602 datasheet shows how output swing is affected by current being sunk/sourced by the output:

Since you need the output to swing as low as 150mV above ground (\$V_{SS}=0V\$), you should take care not to approach the 100mV point on the lower plot, for some margin. That occurs near an output current just shy of 3mA, so make sure you never get near 3mA of output current. The highest output potential you require is several hundred millivolts less than \$V_{DD}=+3.3V\$, and isn't such a concern.
There are two causes for output current, the feedback resistors, and whatever else you connect to it (the load). To keep feedback current as small as possible, resistances should be larger than those you are currently using. Make sure that whatever load you connect has an input impedance well over 10kΩ.
You will have to attenuate the input signal somewhat, so that it never exceeds +2.1V. I'll limit it to less than +2.0V, using a potential divider with gain under \$\frac{2.0}{2.6}=0.77\$. Using E12 resistor values, the nearest I can get to gain 0.77 (without exceeding it) is:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If I call this gain \$A_1 = 0.764\$, then the voltage range at X, presented to the op-amp amplifier will be:
$$ (+0.8V, +2.6V) \times A_1 = (0.61V, 1.99V) $$
The new gain \$A_2\$ of the amplifier becomes:
$$ A_2 = \frac{2.95 - 0.15}{1.99 - 0.61} = 2.03 $$
The system will have this form:

simulate this circuit
Gain of the op-amp stage is \$1+\frac{47k}{45.63k}=2.03\$, as required, and the source of +1.059 is chosen to produce \$V_{OUT}=+0.15V\$ when \$V_{IN}=+0.8V\$. Since you don't have a source of +1.059V, you create one using another potential divider, whose Thevenin equivalent consists of Vth and Rth above. In other words, Thevenin voltage is +1.059, and Thevenin resistance is 45.63kΩ. The divider will use the +3.3V supply, since that's a low impedance source you do have:
$$ R_3 \parallel R_4 = R_{TH} = 45.63k\Omega $$
$$ 3.3V \times \frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} = V_{TH} = 1.059V $$

simulate this circuit

This design is the same as yours, with the addition of the resistor divider at the input, and resistor values changed to suit.
The design depends on a precise and steady +3.3V source. If there's any noise or fluctuation on that rail, then this will be injected into the signal (via divider R3/R4), and some fraction of it will appear at OUT. I only mention this because you said that there seems to be some fluctuation in the output even when the input is steady, and it could well come from the supply.
One solution would be to use a precision voltage reference like the TL431, instead of the positive supply rail, but that's another story.

I've assembled this in a breadboard; the lower band is correct at 150mV but the output saturates at 2V (the output voltage does not increase for the last quarter of moving the magnet). I've checked the hall effect signal coming into the op amp is (0.62V, 1.99V). Any ideas?

To confirm, I replaced the 47k feedback resistor with a 68k to force the output to the rails and it still saturates at 2V.

Current draw for the whole circuit is <3.2mA

@LeeTaylor The evidence suggests this isn't rail-to-rail output, not an MCP602. This is behaviour I would expect from an LM358 or similar. From whom did you buy this op-amp?
